# UpdatePanel mangling my querystring

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a LinkButton that is posting back inside an UpdatePanel.  I then process the data in the event handler and then want to do a redirect after processing. I am trying to use Response.Redirect with a url like  "pagename.aspx?clientid=14".  When I do that the "?" and "=" get encoded.  Of course the browser can't use a url with the "?" encoded so it bombs.  I swear I have never had trouble with this before but I just started a new project in .net 4.0 thought there might be some new fangled security stuff I don't know about.

What I want: "http://site.site.com/ViewUserPermissions.aspx?StaffId=05786"

What I get instead: "http://site.site.com/%2fViewUserPermissions.aspx%3fStaffId%3d05786"

*Also note*:  This is an intranet app.  I don't care about hacker attacks and don't need any type of security for that.

Comment: How are you accessing the query string parameters in code?  Can you post a little snippet?

Comment: @subt13: I don't get that far.  The browser can't handle an encoded ? for the querystring marker so I get a Page can't be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version works fine, but it doesn't automatically update your web.config with the new reference. Make sure you have the proper System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule HttpModule registered from the System.Web.Extensions assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I went back to using the default ScriptManager.  I had upgraded to the latest AjaxToolkit script manager.  Apparently it is broken.  I think that library gets worse with each release.